# Regex for sting upto 24 characters limit, but should have atleast 10-16 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to come up with a regex expression. The user can enter a string from with minimum 10 characters and maximum 24 characters, but the string should contain 10 digits and can have a maximum of 16 digits in it.

can someone help. I tried using `(?=[0-9]{10,16}) (?=.{10,24})$`

Comment: Try [`^(?=([^0-9]*[0-9]){10,16}[^0-9]*$).{10,24}$`](https://regex101.com/r/RGYzsH/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
/^(?=.{10,24}$)\D*(?:\d\D*){10,16}$/
```

The lookahead expression checks the string length, the one after checks the number of digits.

Here's [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL2Tfs/1); I've decreased the limits quite a bit for obvious reasons.

---

The key difference with your pattern is usage of `\D*(?:\d\D*)` expression; without it only the direct sequence of digits will be matched.

Comment: Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could always use string match for /[0-9]/g and calc the length of the returned array.

```
> '93k03k30dk30483'.match(/[0-9]/g).length
11
```